# How could I alter the way that elastic search sort a field?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, mapping, sense, nosql

I need to sort a field in Elastic Search and set the following symbol "_" with higher precedence over the numbers.

Let's say I have the following:

```
"1"
"2"
"_3"
```

The sorting I want should sort as follows:

```
"_3"
"1"
"2"
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that field a `string` correct?

Comment: And how do you want the sorting to happen for `_3`, `_2`, `_5`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan In that case it is first the "_" and then the numeric. It would be: _2, _3, _5

Comment: Are there any limits to what these numbers can be? There might be the need to use a trick involving a very high number or a very low numer to be able to sort these.

Comment: @AndreiStefan No, there is no way to limit them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like the following, if you know that some number can't possibly be added as valid ones in the documents:

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "if (doc['messageText'].value.startsWith('_')) return doc['messageText'].value.substring(1).toInteger()-1000000; return doc['messageText'].value.toInteger()",
      "type": "number",
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```